# Retaining old bundles with SDK 33 requirement

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an Android app, and typically use retained bundles in order to support old devices. For example, my latest release has a new bundle that targets SDK 33 with a minimum SDK 26. However, it includes several retained bundles, with the oldest one targeting SDK 27 with minimum SDK 19. This has worked well for a long time. But now Play Store is saying that in order to update the app after August 31 2023, there may be no retained bundles that target an SDK version < 33. So that seems to mean that I must remove all retained bundles from before a year ago that would not target SDK 33. Am I understanding that correctly? What then is the way to support older devices without having to support a lower minimum SDK in the latest version?

I sent these questions to Play Console Support, but their boilerplate answers weren't very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retained bundles will still be supported in Play. This is [officially announced](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/231996197/target-api-level-extension-form-new-help-content?hl=en-GB&sjid=1067590827206894208-EU)

> Can I still release updates to my app that include retained bundles which target older Target API versions?
>
> Yes, existing & retained bundles will still be able to be used in new releases, identical to previous years. Only new bundles which don’t comply with the updated Target API requirements will be unable to be released.

However, new bundles must target SDK 33.

Comment: So glad to see that. It's a sigh of relief. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are understanding the situation correctly. Starting from August 31, 2023, Google Play Store's policy requires that if you have retained bundles, none of them can target an SDK version below 33. This means that you need to remove all retained bundles targeting SDK versions lower than 33 to comply with the new policy.

The challenge you're facing is how to support older devices while adhering to the new policy without reducing the minimum SDK version of your latest release. One possible approach is to use dynamic feature modules. You can split your app's functionality into separate dynamic modules, each with its own minimum SDK version. This way, you can maintain a higher minimum SDK version for your main app module while providing lower minimum SDK versions for specific feature modules that are downloaded on-demand for older devices.

Comment: Thanks @adnan-ali. My app is Cordova hybrid app, so not sure if dynamic feature modules will be practical. It sounds like unfortunately I will have to drop these retained bundles, and if a user has an old device offer them a direct download from "unknown source".